# Search for string and delete line that contains string and the line underneath

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains

```
### 174.10.150.10 on 2018-06-20 12:19:47.533613 ###
IP : 174.10.150.10 : 

IP : ALL :
```

I currently have code that uses Regex to search for a date/time string.
How can I delete a line that contains the string that I find?  I want to delete that line and also the line underneath.

So both of these lines would get deleted:

```
### 174.10.150.10 on 2018-06-20 12:19:47.533613 ###
IP : 174.10.150.10 :
```

My code currently just adds 'None' to the bottom of the text file.

```
import re

def run():  
    try:
        with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
            with open('file.txt', 'a') as f2:
                reg = re.compile('###\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{0,})\s###')
                for line in f:
                    m = reg.match(line)
                answer = raw_input("Delete line? ")
                if answer == "y":

                    # delete line that contains "###" and line underneath
                    f2.write(str(m))

                else:
                    print("You chose no.")
    except OSError as e:
        print (e)

run()
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the lines in your code that ask if those lines should be deleted? Do you want to overwrite `file.txt` with the file with those two lines deleted? Your code now is meant for Python 2--do you want the answer to be for Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: first: if you want to delete the line with the date, you should in case of "Delete line?" == 'yes' use _no write command at all_. And to delete the next line, too, you would have to add a Counter, which is started as soon as the question is answered "yes", end set back when reached the number of following lines to be deleted (1 in your case).

Comment: And btw: you iterate over all those lines checking for a regex match but doing nothing else and also do not use each result m - and _afterwards_ your question part with the if-structure is following; therefore only handling the very last `m`, hence: adding `None` to your result file f2.

Comment: I want to overwrite file.txt with the same file that has those 2 lines deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**EDIT:** I now understand from your comments that you have a blank line after two data lines, so when you want to delete a line you also want to delete the next *two* lines. My code has been adjusted to do that.)

Here is some code, making various changes to your code. I wrote a new file rather than overwriting the old file, for safety and to avoid needing to keep the entire file in memory at once. I combined the `with` lines into one line, for readability; similarly, I split the regex string to allow shorter lines of code. To avoid having more than one line in memory at once, I used a countdown variable `skipline` to note if a line is to be skipped in the new file. I also show each line before asking whether or not to delete it (with its following line). Note that lines that do not have the date and time are copied, by checking that the regexp match variable is `None`. Finally, I changed `raw_input` to `input` so this code will run in Python 3. Change it back to `raw_input` for Python 2.

By the way, the reason your code just adds `'None'` to the end of the file is that you put your `write` line *outside* the main loop over the lines of the file. Thus you write only the regex match object for the last line of the file. Since the last line in your file does not have a date and time, the regex did not match so the string representation of the failed match is `'None'`. In your second `with` statement you opened `file.txt` in *append* mode, so that `'None'` is appended to the file.

I want to emphasize that you should create a new file. If you really want to overwrite the old file, the safe way to do that is to create a new file first with a slightly different name. Then if that file is made successfully, overwrite the old file with the new file and rename one copy to something like `file.bak`. This takes possible OS errors into account, as your code attempts to do. Without something like that, an error could end up deleting your file completely or mangling it. I leave that part of the code to you.

```
import re

def run():  
    try:
        with open('file.txt', 'r') as f, open('file.tmp', 'w') as f2:
            reg = re.compile('###\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
                             '.+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}'
                             ':\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{0,})\s###')
            skipline = 0  # do not skip lines
            for line in f:
                if skipline:
                    skipline -= 1
                    continue  # Don't write or process this line
                m = reg.match(line)
                if m:
                    answer = input("Delete line {} ? ".format(m.group()))
                    if answer == "y":
                        skipline = 2 # leave out this and next 2 lines
                    else:
                        print("You chose no.")
                if not skipline:
                    f2.write(line)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)

run()
```

Comment: Thank you!  There is a lot more to my code than that.  I tried simplifying some things.  You're example helped me a lot.

Comment: One thing, when there are several lines starting with "###" and I run this, it removes them properly and saves the new data to file2.txt.  But I noticed it leaves a bunch of blank space or new lines at the top of file2.txt.  Is there a way to stop this?  Would the strip() method work in some way?

Comment: Does your file have a blank line after each of the two lines that you want to remove? Your example does not make that clear and you did not say. If so, you probably want to remove *two* lines after the date/time line. That can be done by changing the flag variable `skiplines` from a Boolean to an integer: start it at 2 and count down to 0. If you just want to remove blank lines at the top of the file, another Boolean flag variable could take care of that. If you give more details about your files I can give more details about a solution.

Comment: The 2 top lines in my example may be listed several times with different IP addresses and date/time information.  There is an empty line between each set of 2 lines.  So each time new data is added to the file, 2 lines with an empty line underneath will be added to the top of the file.  When I run your code, all sets of 2 lines are removed from the top of the file but empty lines are still remaining.  As if the lines are not deleted, they are just cleared. When I add 2 new lines again, they are added above the empty lines where other data used to be.

Comment: I edited my code to delete the next *two* lines after the chosen line to delete. I made some other minor changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

With some basic refactoring, here's the result...

```
import re
valid_lines = []

def run():  
    try:
        with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
            reg = re.compile('###\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{0,})\s###\s?')
            lines = f.readlines()
            invalid_index = -10

            for a in range(len(lines)):
                reg_result = reg.match(lines[a])

                if invalid_index == (a - 1):
                    # Skip the line underneath the invalid line
                    continue

                if reg_result != None:
                    # If the line matches the regexp.
                    invalid_index = a
                    answer = raw_input("Delete line? ")

                    if answer.lower() != 'y':
                        print("You chose no.")
                        valid_lines.append(lines[a])
                else:
                    valid_lines.append(lines[a])

        with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
            # Override the file...
            f.writelines(valid_lines)

    except OSError as e:
        print (e)

run()
```

If you want to remove any lines that start with `###` then, **maybe** you should consider this as the regexp: `###.*`

**EDIT:** In your regular expression, you should add a `\s?` at the end to optionally match `\n`, as the file contains newlines. Also, use `fullmatch()` instead of `match()`.

Comment: These deletes all lines.

Answer (score 1):

I refactor the filtering part into a function called `filter_lines` and move the regex as module variable. This approach make use of iterator.

```
import re

regex = re.compile('###\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{0,})\s###')

def filter_lines(lines):
    it = iter(lines)

    try:
        while True:
            line = next(it)
            m = regex.match(line)

            if m:
                # You may add the question-answer code here to ask the user whether delete the matched line.
                next(it)  # Comsume the line following the commented line
                continue

            yield line
    except StopIteration:
        # In the future, StopIteration raised in generator function will be converted to RuntimeError so it have to be caught.
        # https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/
        pass

def run():  
    try:
        with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
            with open('file.txt', 'a') as f2:
                filtered_lines = list(filter_lines(f1.readlines()))
                print(*filtered_lines, sep='')
                # You may use the following line to actually write the result to a file
                # f2.writelines(filtered_lines)
    except OSError as e:
        print (e)

run()
```

This program should print the resultant content.